# Module Manager - Search by Module ID? It is not easy to find/locate modules for editing

Tags: module, module-manager

I'm working on a very large site with hundreds of modules. It would be convenient to have a search field where the Module ID could be entered. There are filters for every other column (position, category, etc). The only text input allows user to search by title - but why can't the backend be searched for Module ID? It is possible to sort by Module ID, but that is a time drag because the site is huge and slow.

Does this functionality exist, or would it be possible to add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search with `id:123` where 123 is your module id. This works in most of the admin side to search by an id value.

Comment: Thanks David, that does the trick! Why didn't I know that?

Comment: At least you know now! Accept the answer to let others know that this worked for you.